# Dapr app channel not initialized, make sure -app-port is specified if pubsub subscription is required

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, dapr

I am trying to implement subcriber in C# console app using Dapr, but its giving the below error.

**Error:**

> app channel not initialized, make sure -app-port is specified if
> pubsub subscription is required
>
> Exited App successfully
>
> terminated signal received: shutting down Exited Dapr successfully

**Code:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DaprClient _dapr = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();
    _dapr.PublishEventAsync("pubSubName", "topicName", "data");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue by converting the console app to windows (worker) service.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
})
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults((builder) =>
{
    builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
});

public  class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDaprClient();
    }
    public void Configure()
    {
    }
}

public class MyService: BackgroundService
{
    private readonly DaprClient _dapr;

    public PaymentService(DaprClient dapr)
    {
        _dapr = dapr;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _dapr.PublishEventAsync();
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```